# Text does not fit into table which causes bad box errors

Tags: tables, line-breaking, excel

I use Excel2Latex to convert tables in Excel to Latex, however a problem arises when the text is too long to fit in the column and I get many bad box errors. My code is:

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_hours}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The average number of hours worked each week by the respondent} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_hours\_dummy}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the respondent works more than 0 hours each week, and zero otherwise} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_age}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The age (in years) of the woman} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_educ}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The number of years of formal education of the woman} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_exper}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The woman's work experience (in years)} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Hus\_age}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The age (in years) of the woman's husband} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Hus\_educ}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The number of years of formal education of the woman's husband} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Hus\_inc}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The annual income (in \$'000s) of the woman's husband} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{faminc}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The annual income (in \$'000s) of the family unit} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{kids05}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The number of children under the age of 6} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{kids618}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The number of children aged between 6 and 18} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{largecity}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the woman lives in a large city, and zero otherwise} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_mothereduc}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The number of years of formal education of the woman's mother} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_fathereduc}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The number of years of education of the woman's father} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{W\_motherworked}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the woman's mother was herself a working mum, and zero otherwise} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Hus\_mothereduc}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The number of years of formal education of the woman's husband's mother} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Hus\_fathereduc}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{The numbger of years education of the woman's husband's father} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Hus\_motherworked}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the woman's husband's mother was herself a working mum, and zero otherwise} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

The resulting table produced looks like:

[image: table]

What are some solutions to this?

Comment: After seeing the output of Excel2LaTeX, I'd suggest you to abandon it altogether: the produced code is unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\itshape}lX @{}}\toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}}\\ \midrule
W\_hours          & The average number of hours worked each week by the respondent \\
W\_hours\_dummy   & A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the respondent works more than 0 hours each week, and zero otherwise \\
W\_age            & The age (in years) of the woman \\
W\_educ           & The number of years of formal education of the woman \\
W\_exper          & The woman's work experience (in years) \\
Hus\_age          & The age (in years) of the woman's husband \\
Hus\_educ         & The number of years of formal education of the woman's husband \\
Hus\_inc          & The annual income (in \$'000s) of the woman's husband \\
faminc            & The annual income (in \$'000s) of the family unit \\
kids05            & The number of children under the age of 6 \\
kids618           & The number of children aged between 6 and 18 \\
largecity         & A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the woman lives in a large city, and zero otherwise \\
W\_mothereduc     & The number of years of formal education of the woman's mother \\
W\_fathereduc     & The number of years of education of the woman's father \\
W\_motherworked   & A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the woman's mother was herself a working mum, and zero otherwise \\
Hus\_mothereduc   & The number of years of formal education of the woman's husband's mother \\
Hus\_fathereduc   & The numbger of years education of the woman's husband's father \\
Hus\_motherworked & A dummy variable that takes the value of unity if the woman's husband's mother was herself a working mum, and zero otherwise \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: recommended to use ragged right in the multi-line cells.  it avoids the uneven spacing and suppresses hyphenation, and rarely adds lines.

Comment: in general yes but not for the above tabular.

Comment: okay, but i'm not sure why.  the `tabularx` manual does mention the need to specify `\arraybackslash`, so for this data, the tabular preamble of `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\itshape}l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{}}` has the expected effect.  since the data will be generated programmatically, if a line does contain `\\` there would be problems, but the description doesn't lead me to believe that `\\` would be in the data.

Comment: I meant that it makes no sense to use `\raggedright` because the columns are well typeset.

Comment: okay.  subjective.  (i find several of the lines to be a bit spacier than i would find ideal, for example the second entry, and the one that begins "A dummy variable".)  i thought you were referring to a technical reason.